# How to remove "Burn with Nero" from context menu in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, context-menu, nero

How to remove `Burn with Nero` from context menu in Windows 7?

I have tried to find in Nero Burning Rom such option but without success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

x86:

```
regsvr32 /u "%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Nero\NeroShellExt\NeroShellExt.dll"
```

x64:

```
regsvr32 /u "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Common Files\Nero\NeroShellExt\NeroShellExt.dll"
```

If you get error message with code 0x80070005, create new shortcut and put appropriate line in it, than right-click that shortcut and "Run As Admin"

Comment: For Nero 2021 the shell extension is located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Nero\Nero 2021\Nero Burning ROM\x64`. You can also just "run" the `shellreg64uninstall.reg` in that folder.

Answer (score 5):

Use [ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) or [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to remove the annoying context menu entry.

Comment: ShellMenuView and ShellExView are really great programs and thanks for that, but i haven't find any listed item that have "Nero" in it. I have Windows 7 64 bit and "Nero Burning Rom" context menu is not showing in Windows Explorer but only in Total Commander context menu. I think that Total Commander is showing 32 bit context menu.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Menu Maid](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/MenuMaid.shtml) for these tasks

> MenuMaid offers a simple yet powerful software solution for helping you get rid of context menu items that occupy space on the computer and slow down system performance. It can be easily configured by all types of users, regardless of their experience level.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Nero 2018 / Windows 10 go to

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Nero\Nero 2018\NeroShellExt\x64*

Run *shellreg64uninstall.reg* to remove it from Windows Explorer context menu.

Comment: For Nero 2021 the folder path is: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Nero\Nero 2021\Nero Burning ROM\x64`

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a bit more to remove Nero context menu.

I used [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html). Disabling the entry didn't work. So, I did a right-click and selected ***Open CLSID In RegEdit*** and then removed the entry:
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{SOME_ID_NUMBER}`

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest [autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) for it.
It's a Microsoft tool, very powerful, and can do this quite easily.